# angular-cli is not installing on osX Sierra

Tags: macos, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am using mac osX Sierra When angular-cli was not installing I tried force install , tried installation by yarn but nothing changed those installation said that angular-cli was installed successfully but when i write ng -v or ng --version or ng --help or ng -help all the time i gave me same error massage and i could not work with angular cli :(

```
success Installed angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.19-3 with binaries:
  - ng
✨  Done in 24.96s.
MDSAZIDs-iMac:~ MYMAC$ ng -v
module.js:457
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'rsvp'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/MYMAC/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/ext/promise.js:3:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: Try to run ng command from your created folder. For example create folder in Documents. This worked for me.

Comment: The `1.0.0-beta.19-3` hasn't been released officially. Try eg. the plain `1.0.0-beta.19`.

Comment: i used this tutorial to solve my installation problem..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mtlrXYKsZ0&index=1&list=PLrMggSuNOco6iLjrCOsO1_UKmJQosr7_g

Comment: I have solved this problem from a video tutorial . i guess its a problem of node js it self and now the instructions are outdated so it might not work for you... but i will leave it there in hope that you may find some idea from that the link is :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mtlrXYKsZ0